# Fullcalendar: How to add a new button to the existing buttons in header?

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, fullcalendar

I am trying to add a new button to the existing buttons in the header. I am not able to find out how to do it. Presently, i have prev,next,today,month,agendaWeek,agendaDay in the header. I want one more button to add new events. So that after click of the button, i could add new events through a pop up.

My code is as follows:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({ 
utc: true, 
header: { 
left: 'prev,next today', 
center: 'title', 
right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay' 
}, 
editable: true, 
droppable: true, 

eventAfterRender: function(event, element, view) { 
element.append(event.title); 
} 

});
```

My html code is as follows:-

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8' />
<link href='fullcalendar-2.7.1/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='fullcalendar-2.7.1/fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet'    media='print' />
<script src='fullcalendar-2.7.1/lib/moment.min.js' type='text/javascript'>   </script>
<script src='fullcalendar-2.7.1/lib/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar-2.7.1/lib/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar-2.7.1/lib/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
 </head>
 <body>  
 <div id='calendar'></div>
 </body>
```

Is there a way to do it through FullCalendar? Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can add custom button using this code:

```
 $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
    customButtons: {
        add_event: {
            text: 'Add',
            click: function() {
               alert(); 
            }
        }
    },
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'add_event'
    },
 });
```

Comment: yeah thanks pranav,now i need a form on click of the button. how to get a form?

Comment: You can create modal with bootstrap reffer this : http://www.mikesmithdev.com/blog/fullcalendar-event-details-with-bootstrap-modal/

Comment: can you shoe me a fiddle pls?

Comment: Update "headerToolbar:" instead of "header"